# Rotate text in landscape mode

Tags: java, rotation, graphics2d

I'm trying to print a rotated number "999" in the upper left corner of a report that is set to landscape. The characters should be placed about 1/2" in and 1" down from the top but nothing is printing so far. Here's my code:

```
haX = 30;
haY = 100;
AffineTransform at = g2d.getTransform();
g2d.translate(haX + haY, 0); 
g2d.rotate(-Math.PI/2);
Font rotatedFont = new Font(font.getFontName(), font.getStyle(), fs );
rotatedFont = rotatedFont.deriveFont(at);
g2d.setFont(rotatedFont);
g2d.drawString("999", haX, haY);
g2d.setTransform(at);
```

Any ideas would really be appreciated.
Thanks
Elliot

Comment: You need to call `repaint()` for the component you draw on. Did you?

Comment: Yes it's called elsewhere. The rest of the report prints fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You do not need an `AffineTransform`, the `rotate` method is a special case of it. I also don't know why you call `translate` since you already know the location at which you draw.
Here is how to rotate text:

```
public class Draw extends JFrame {

    Draw() {

        setContentPane(new MyPanel());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(300,300);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    class MyPanel extends JPanel {

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
            int haX = 30;
            int haY = 100;
            g2d.rotate(-Math.PI/2, haX, haY);
            g2d.drawString("999", haX, haY);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Draw();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Elliot If this solves your problem please consider accepting the answer, or upvoting if it was helpful.